# What is the operation of quasigroup in this example?

Tags: group-theory, latin-square, combinatorial-designs

This example is taken from [here](http://www.cimpa.info/archivesecoles/20140205111906/lindner@201-2.pdf).

A quasigroup of order n is a pair (Q, o), where Q is a set of size n and "o" is a binary operation on Q s. t. for every pair of elements $a,b\in Q$ the equations $a$ o $x = b$ and $y$ o $a = b$ have unique solutions.

[image]

for example see the figure, I'm trying to figure out what is the operation. So far, I know it is closed under this operation because each value in the table is between 1-5. Honestly, the definition cannot tell how to compute the table.

Comment: It's probably analogous to defining a permutation $\pi$ by $1 \mapsto 5 \mapsto 3 \mapsto 4 \mapsto 1$; there doesn't have to be any rhyme or reason, they *tell you* what the products of various elements are.

Comment: @pjs36 it sounds logic so each row has a unique permutation. e.g. 3rd row: 3,1245. 4th row: 4, 1352. 5th row: 5, 1423.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to your question: you're given multiplication table. So result of $1 \circ 3$ is $2$, and $2 \circ 4$ is $1$.

Long comment: there's a general notion of a magma $(X, *)$, which is just a set $X$ with an operation $*$, i. e. arbitrary map $$X \times X \rightarrow X, \quad (x_1, x_2) \mapsto x_1 * x_2 $$ (and your multiplication table is perfect example of such a map). But you can think about a map from $X \times X$ as bunch of maps from "right $X$" labeled by elements of "left $X$" — that is, you'll completely decribe your operation $*$ if you define individual maps of *left multiplication by* $x$: $(x\,* -)$ for each element $x \in X$; this approach will give you $$X \to Fun(X, X), \quad x \mapsto (x\,* -)$$ It's pretty obvious that every operation gives unique labeling of elements by their left multiplication maps and vise versa; same for right multiplication. But you need to be careful there: functions are composition-associative, whereas your operation is not guaranteed to be associative! So composing multiplication-by-$x$ with multiplication-by-$y$ (as maps from $X$ to itself) is not same as multiplying by $y * x$. (in your example $(1 \circ (1 \circ 2)) = 4 \neq 5 = ((1 \circ 1) \circ 2)$)

Now back to your example. Quasigroup is a particular type of a magma, where left and right multiplication operators are bijective (mentioned equations have unique solutions $\iff$ preimage of each element under every (left or right) multiplication-by-something is one element). So, quasigroup operation is a map 
$$X \times X \rightarrow X, \quad (x_1, x_2) \mapsto x_1 \circ x_2 $$
which restricts to a bijections $$\{x\} \times X \cong X, \, X \times \{x\} \cong X$$ for each $x \in X$. And it's exactly the definition of a latin square — every row $(\{x\} \times X)$ and every column $(X \times \{x\})$ contain each number exactly once (bijectivity).

Also note that not every map $$X \to Sym(X), \quad x \mapsto (x\,* -)$$ will give a quasigroup — for example, sending all $X$ to one element will not succeed; injectivity is not enough too, and you can construct counterexample very easy.

Comment: Thank you! I have a question: So, we need to specify the value of function like: F(i,i)=i, and F(1,2)=5, F(1,3)=2, F(1,4)=3, F(1,5)=4, F(2,3)=4, F(2,4)=1, F(2,5)=3, F(3,4)=5, F(3,5)=1, F(4,5)=2. and we know that it is symmetric, so if we have n x n multiplication table, then we have n(n-1)/2 number of functions that we need to specify for this operation. Is that right!!

Comment: Since the set $Q$ is finite, you can define an operation by listing all the possible products $a \circ b$, where $a, b \in Q$. That is a total of $n^2$ operations ($25$ in your example). In this case you can see from the multiplication table that the operation is commutative. Then you only need the products $a \circ b$, where $a \geq b$. That is $\frac{(n+1)n}{2}$ operations ($15$ in the example).

Comment: Ok, only now I think I understood your comment... So if you happen to know that the operation is commutative AND you also know that every element is idempotent (that is, $a \circ a = a$ for every $a \in Q$, or $F(i,i)=i$ as you said), then yes, you need to know an additional $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ products to have all the information.

Comment: @Leppala I understood , thank you for clarifying more about this question!